# TikZ: Keeping nodes clear from lines

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I set all nodes and coordinates that I can be set right away in the at the top of the `TikZ` picture.  However, a line can obstruct the node.  If the node is after the line, I could use `fill = white` which will white out that portion of the line.  Can I achieve something like this without moving the nodes below the offending line or lines?  I know we could suggest moving the node, but in some cases, this wouldn't be the case.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  every label/.append style = {font = \small},
  dot/.style = {outer sep = +0pt, inner sep = +0pt,
    shape = circle, draw = black, label = {#1}},
  dot/.default =,
  small dot/.style = {minimum size = .1cm, dot = {#1}},
  small dot/.default =,
  big dot/.style = {minimum size = .15cm, dot = {#1}},
  big dot/.default =
  ]
  \node[scale = .75, fill = black, big dot = {below: \(F\)}]
    (F) at (2.5, 0) {};

  \draw (2.5, 1) -- (2.5, -1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you *show* what you want achieve instead?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel the whiteout background without having to place the nodes below the lines.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel picture of intent added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `backgrounds` library to put the line on a "background layer", and then fill the node with white:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{backgrounds} % use backgrounds library

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  every label/.append style = {font = \small},
  dot/.style = {outer sep = +0pt, inner sep = +0pt,
    shape = circle, draw = black, label = {#1}},
  dot/.default =,
  small dot/.style = {minimum size = .1cm, dot = {#1}},
  small dot/.default =,
  big dot/.style = {minimum size = .15cm, dot = {#1}},
  big dot/.default =
  ]
  \node[scale = .75, fill = black, big dot = {below,fill=white: \(F\)}]
    (F) at (2.5, 0) {};

  % put line on background layer
  \begin{scope}[on background layer]
  \draw (2.5, 1) -- (2.5, -1);
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works but doesn't.  The nodes are placed to high now and below seems to not work now when I try `below = .xcm` where `x` are numbers I have tried.

Comment: Another potential problem I may encounter, with this solutions, is that if later on I define a node built off the other lines, I would have to keep stacking `{scope}[on background layer]`.  I would like to avoid stacking a bunch of these as well.

Comment: @dustin: The first issue you raised can be solved by using the key `label distance=<length>`. Right now I don't have a quick fix for the second issue, though...

Comment: @dustin: I've played with the codes a bit, and it seems that TikZ doesn't really support *nested* layers, if that's what you mean by "stacking". However, if by "stacking" you just mean having to repeatedly type `{scope}[on background layer]` and so on, you can simplify by defining a macro, say `\bg`, as `\newcommand\bg[1]{\begin{scope}[on background layer] #1 \end{scope}}`, and use `\bg{\draw ... ;}` to draw lines that need to be on the background layer